# Configure firefox to not send hidden authentication data to third party sites?(Just Like tor browser does)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, firefox

I am configuring Firefox(for android) to reduce browser fingerprinting and to make it more anonymous like the tor browser. I use Orbot for connecting to Tor. I tried to use the ublock addon to block all third party sites. That does work but it prevents many web pages from loading. What key should i edit it about:config so as to make firefox not send http authentication data via its headers. Is it possible like that or do i require any addon?

Comment: This is a question about firefox, not Tor or even Tor Browser?

Comment: But tor browser modifies firefox's configuration right? Did i post this in the wrong place?

Comment: Do you know about OrFox? The project invested quite some into configuring it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're even asking, what is "hidden authentication data"? and what do you mean by "http authentication data"? many of Tor Browsers fingerprinting resistance mechanisms are patches for the Firefox code, you cannot make Firefox act like Tor Browser through configuration. You should just use Tor Browser.

Comment: I got this from the jondonym's ip-check.info website. 
Many browsers allow web sites to send hidden authentication data to third party sites. Example:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://Session:638431048@ipcheck.info/auth.css.php">

This may either happen directly on the current page or in an iframe, and does NOT need JavaScript. If additionally iFrames and JavaScript are used, even the currently loaded page may get your ID. This data is deleted when the browser is closed, but, execpt for this, has the same effect as third party cookies.

Comment: I guess i should use the orfox browser instead. But i was wondering if i could make firefox more anonymous.

Comment: Tor Browser doesn't disable this, it just uses the New Identity button to clear the settings to break any tracking that may have been set.
See https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#new-identity